# Git Commit - Why isn't GitBash launching my default text editor (sublime) for me to enter commit message

Tags: git, bash, git-commit, git-config

I am following [this MOOC](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud775/lessons/2980038599/concepts/33417185870923) to learn about Git. Following [this video](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud775/lessons/2969618657/concepts/29605487740923), I want to make my first commit in my repository. So I ran **`git commit`** command, expecting that Sublime Text Editor will be launched where I will enter my *commit message*. **But I got the following error. The question is that how do I fix this.**

```
Jojoa (master +) Directory for practice $ git commit
'C:/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text.exe' -n -w: C:/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text.exe: No such file or directory
error: There was a problem with the editor ''C:/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text.exe' -n -w'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

---

***How I had set up Sublime Text as Default Editor:***

Using [this lesson](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud775/lessons/2980038599/concepts/33417185870923) as a guide, I ran the following command to set up Sublime Text as my default text editor.

```
git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text \2/sublime_text.exe' -n -w"
```

Then I ran `C:/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text \2/sublime_text.exe` and this launched the Sublime Text editor. This verified that the above command worked properly.

Then I went ahead to edit the .bash_profile configuration file in the sublime text editor to add the following line to it:

```
alias sublime = "C:/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text \2/sublime_text.exe"
```

Then I closed and opened Git Bash and ran `sublime`. This opened the Sublime Text Editor. So I got certain that the workspace has been set up correctly.

Comment: I think you should either remove the single quotes or the escape characters: `Program\ Files` or `'Program Files'`

Comment: @andlrc But it opens sublime editor with the simple command `sublime`, and that means the editor is configured correctly. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work for you:

```
git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text.exe' -n -w"
```

The reason your alias works is because it gets expanded by the shell:

```
alias sublime="C:/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text.exe"
sublime -> C:/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text.exe ->
'C:/Program Files/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text.exe'
```

FYI, an alias is only in the shells memory and cannot be used by any process called by the shell, you could create a script called: `subl` and place it somewhere in your `$PATH`:

```
$ echo "$PATH"
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/home/USER/bin
$ cat "$HOME/bin/subl"
#!/bin/sh
'C:/Program Files/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text.exe' "$@"
```

The above will enable you to use the command `subl` everywhere, even as git core.editor:

```
git config --global core.editor 'subl -n -w'
```

Alternative you can set `$VISUAL` or `$EDITOR` environment variables which git will use if no core.editor is set:

```
export EDITOR="C:/Program Files/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, Git uses whatever you’ve set as your default text editor (`$VISUAL` or `$EDITOR`) or else falls back to the vi editor to create and edit your commit and tag messages. To change that default to something else, you can use the `core.editor` setting:

```
$ git config --global core.editor emacs
```

Now, no matter what is set as your default shell editor, Git will fire up Emacs to edit messages.